# Unity 5. Command Invocation Faliure

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

This question seems to get asked a lot because this error seems to cover a multitude of problems. None of the answers I can find on here or else where apply to my problem.

Here's the full error:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the
>   Console for details.
>   C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe
>   package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   "res" -I
>   "C:/Users/id/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar"
>   -F bin/resources.ap_
>
> stderr[
>
> ] stdout[
>
> ] UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
>   psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String
>   command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[]
>   progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources
>   (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName,
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal
>   (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea,
>   System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String
>   companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget
>   target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea,
>   System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String
>   companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

This is a new install and the project was building before. I'm reasonably sure I've got the JDK and Android SDK set up right but I could be wrong.

Any pointers or hints appreciated.